# How do I use Fmincon function (MATLAB) for curve fitting with four independent variables

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have the experimental data (xlsx file) to be used for curve fitting through Matlab. I'm trying to fit the experimental stress data, which are denoted by, to the analytical equivalent (Gent model) defined using function J with four independent variables to be evaluated. However, the following code using Fmincon and globalsearch optimization doesn't work for more than two variables. Could someon please suggest me a way to modify the code to evaluate the four variables{x(1),X(2),x(3), and x(4)} from the curve fitting?

`J = @(x,Filled_stretchextensometer) exp((((-x(1)./2).*(x(2)).*(log(x(2)-(Filled_stretchextensometer.^2+       (2./Filled_stretchextensometer)-3))./x(2))).^x(3)).*((x(4)).^(-x(3)))).*((x(1).*x(2)*(Filled_stretchextensometer-(1./Filled_stretchextensometer.^2))).*(x(2)./(x(2)-(Filled_stretchextensometer.^2+(2./Filled_stretchextensometer)-3))));`

`residue_function = @(x) sum(((exp((((-x(1)./2).*(x(2)).*(log(x(2)-(Filled_stretchextensometer.^2+(2./Filled_stretchextensometer)-3))./x(2))).^x(3)).*(x(4)).^(-x(3))).*((x(1).*x(2)*(Filled_stretchextensometer-(1./Filled_stretchextensometer.^2))).*(x(2)./(x(2)-(Filled_stretchextensometer.^2+(2./Filled_stretchextensometer)-3)))) - predicted_experimentalstress).^2));`

```
 x0 = [49,2,10,12];

   
gs = GlobalSearch;



 problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon', 'x0', x0, 'objective', residue_function, 'lb', [-inf 0]);

   [x, resnorm] = run(gs,problem)



lb = [];



 ub = [];
```